# How to measure mmap I/O latency?

Tags: performance, virtual-memory, mmap, profiling

I have an application which appears to be slowing/blocking at the same time there's a lot of disk I/O going on, so I suspect it's I/O operations within the application which are blocking. I can't imagine what else the problem might be, but I would like to confirm it. The problem is that the application largely uses mmap'd files for I/O, and thus they don't show up with `strace`.
I know blocking I/O operations from mmap'd memory is going to be a page fault. But is there a way to measure the amount of time thread execution was suspended due to page faults?

Answer (score 0):

Yep! `perf record` and `perf stat` can count events for you, such as page misses, per process.

Comment: unfortunately count of page faults does not help me. I need the total latency

Comment: Yep you can also count time spent waiting for specific memory